# Launch app without knowing the url scheme

Tags: iphone, ios, url-scheme

I want to launch another app which is programmed by other programmer in my own app. I know the method of url scheme but the problem is that I do not know the URL scheme of the app that I want to launch. Also, I googled some website to search the URL scheme yet got nothing. I think it's because the app is not used widely.
Is there any way to get the URL scheme??
Or is there another way to launch the app??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can inspect the Info.plist file of the app by extracting the .ipa file:

- Sync the App to iTunes, if necessary.
- Ctrl-Click on the App in iTunes, and use "Show in Finder" to locate the "OtherApp.ipa" file.
- Copy "OtherApp.ipa" to a temporary directory, and use "unzip OtherApp.ipa" on the command line to extract the archive.
- Open "Info.plist" inside the "Payload/OtherApp" folder.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to know that not every app uses URL schemes. It's possible the app you're trying to launch doesn't use them and in that case you're out of luck.
Take a look at the `Info.plist` file inside the app bundle and search for the `CFBundleURLSchemes` key to know if URL schemes are supported.
If you don't find anything I would suggest you to contact the developer directly and telling him what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Whoever downvoted the answer (it wasn't me!): It would be fair to leave a comment why you think that the answer is not useful.